# Do I need to have an activated API key to develop a small app to talk to my own Evernote account?

Tags: evernote

I have a small ruby app that talks to the sandbox server that moves notes between notebooks and adds new notes for the purpose of automating my own weekly workflow. Unfortunately I cant find where I fit in the documentation on evernote, it looks like I need a full blown activated API key in order to work with my own notes on the evernote cloud.

I applied the other day for an activated API key but havent gotten a response (understandable), I am just a little antsy and hoping there is a straightforward approach to messing with my own notes on the cloud.

Is there a way to manage my notes without an activated API key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only need to access your own notes you can use a "dev" token : https://dev.evernote.com/doc/articles/dev_tokens.php

The API key is only useful if you plan to have multiple users.

So :

1. Grab your dev token here : https://www.evernote.com/api/DeveloperToken.action
2. Grab the SDK of your choice
3. Use your dev token as you would use an oauth token (PHP) :

```html
<?php
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

$token = '%token%';

$sandbox = false;

$client = new \Evernote\AdvancedClient($token, $sandbox);
$noteStore = $client->getNoteStore();

// Make API calls
$notebooks = $noteStore->listNotebooks();
foreach ($notebooks as $notebook) {
  print "Notebook: " . $notebook->name . "\n";
}
```

Comment: Does it work for webhook notification for my own account?